# CICD pipeline for nodejs app with no EC2 instances possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

***Can you have a CICD pipeline using AWS codepipeline for a nodejs app without using any EC2 instance for codebuild?***

You would just have ***a code repo -> codebuild -> buildspec file -> Deploy to staging (S3)*** ?

My question is NOT about deploying a lambda function serverlessly but instead, building and deploying a nodejs app without provisioning any spot instances (Ec2), is that doable?

One benefit of this serverless approach to building our nodejs app is:

1. ***Faster developer feedback if tests fail***
2. ***No long startup times since an EC2 can have a variable startup time of 1 - 3mins***

Has anyone achieved this kinda serverless pipeline for building a nodejs app, again NOT building a lambda function but rather building a nodejs app.

Comment: I don't understand - you can't deploy Node.js app to S3. Maybe you just want to build app and upload built artifacts to S3?

Comment: Sorry on wrong language use there; yes, I would like to just build the app and upload the artifacts to S3 WITHOUT PROVISIONING ANY EC2 machines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload build artifacts to S3 - there are 2 ways to achieve that using CodePipeline:

1. Add step with [Invoke Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html)

   or (and I think easier):
2. Upload built app files to S3 from CodeBuild

For 2nd case you can just add [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) like this to your *buildspec.yml*:

```
aws s3 sync --delete <PATH TO BUILT APP FILES> s3://<DESTINATION BUCKET NAME>
```

That will replace whole bucket content with your built app files.